# Adding type for conversion by boost::lexical_cast (segfault)

Tags: c++, boost

I want to convert my type back and forth between string representation and actual data using `boost::lexical_cast`. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;

    Foo(const std::string& str)
        : str(str)
    {
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Foo& foo);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo);

    private:
        std::string str;
};

// For conversion to Foo.
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Foo& foo)
{
    return is >> foo.str;
}

// For conversion from Foo.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo)
{
    return os << foo.str;
}

int main()
{
    boost::lexical_cast<Foo>("ok");
    boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(Foo("ok"));
}
```

But this results in a segfault. Why?

---

[Documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Comment: If you put a `try`/`catch` block around each statement, do you see an exception being thrown? Can you build your program in debug mode and get a stack trace for the crash?

Comment: No, no exceptions are thrown. Stack trace shows gazillion calls to `operator>>`, however.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think the `noexcept` tag makes sense on those functions (`operator>>`, `operator<<`, `Foo::Foo(const std::string&)`), because they allocate memory which can fail with an exception if memory is tight. Admittedly you might consider that such a bad situation that it's not worth handling, but it's still confusing to people reading your code because normally it's only used on functions that do really obviously safe things like swap pointers.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Okay then, I'll remove `noexcept`. You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the crash is due to a stack overflow. I think your `operator>>` is calling itself, by implicitly converting `foo.str` back into a `Foo`.

Try removing the implicit conversion by making that constructor explicit:

```
explicit Foo(const std::string& str) noexcept
    : str(str)
{
}
```